# find object in nested array with lodash

Tags: lodash

I have json data similar to this:

```
    {

  "Sections": [
    {
      "Categories": [
        {
          "Name": "Book",
          "Id": 1,
          "Options": [
            {
              "Name": "AAAA",
              "OptionId": 111
            },
            "Selected": 0
        },
        {
          "Name": "Car",
          "Id": 2,
          "Options": [
            {
              "Name": "BBB",
              "OptionId": 222
            },
            "Selected": 0
        },


      ],
      "SectionName": "Main"
    },
    ... more sections like the one above

  ]
}
```

Given this data, I want to find a category inside a section based on its (Category) Id, and set its selected option, I tried this, but couldn't get it to work....Note Category Id will be unique in the whole data set.

```
_.find(model.Sections, { Categories: [ { Id: catId } ]});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your data model, it looks like you're trying to find an element that is inside a matrix: Sections can have multiple Categories and a Category can have multiple types (car, book...).

I'm afraid there isn't a function in lodash that allows a deep find, you'll have to implement it the 'traditional' way (a couple of fors).

I provide this solution that is a bit more 'functional flavoured' than the traditional nested fors. It also takes advantage of the fact that when you explicitly return false inside a forEach, the loop finishes. Thus, once an element with the provided id is found, the loop is ended and the element returned (if it's not found, `undefined` is returned instead).

Hope it helps.

```js
const findCategoryById = (sections, id) => {
  var category;
  _.forEach(sections, (section) => {
    category = _.find(section.Categories, ['Id', id]);
    return _.isUndefined(category);
  });
  return category;
};


const ex = {
  "Sections": [{
    "Categories": [{
        "Name": "Book",
        "Id": 1,
        "Options": [{
          "Name": "AAAA",
          "OptionId": 111
        }],
        "Selected": 0
      },
      {
        "Name": "Car",
        "Id": 2,
        "Options": [{
          "Name": "BBB",
          "OptionId": 222
        }],
        "Selected": 0
      }
    ],
    "SectionName": "Main"
  }]
};

console.log(findCategoryById(ex.Sections, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```